# How to reload Product price on View page in magento using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have created a checkbox in a separate phtml file and calling this file on my theme default.phtml page . Its is displaying on product view page . When i checked this checkbox and on add to cart page , it increase 10 $ price according to my programming by using observer .

But i want that if some one checked that checkbox on product view page , then its price reload as like it reload for custom option .

Can anyone there , who help me .
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: couldn't you create the tick box as a super attribute on the product so it automatically updates the price?

Comment: can u give me an example of how to do this . I don't have any idea about that .

Comment: sure, open the product in admin.  go to the 'custom options' tab on the left, click 'add new option' in the main screen.  choose type 'checkbox' add a name and a price, save and go and have a look at the product on the frontend

Comment: Custom option is only for one product . Suppose if i have 100 products then i need to create custom option of 100 products which takes a lot of time. So , for avoid this , i created a checkbox in default.phtml page . It is displaying for all product on catalog view page . Now i want if someone click on this checkbox , then price reload on same page .

Comment: checkout Magmi. You can easily import thousands of products with as many custom options as you want in minutes with a spreadsheet, once you get the hang of the syntax.  much neater to stay native when you can

Comment: I want to do it programatically. Tell me how to do please ?

Comment: is your product simple ? and do not have custom-options at all, because there are to many cases